# how can I unmute a conversation in gmail?

Tags: gmail, mute

I have a conversation in gmail that is important to me.  However, I carelessly pressed `m` while viewing it.  This *mutes* the message, so I don't get any updates about it.

I can't seem to find how to unmute it.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To see all the conversations you've got
>   muted, type **is:muted** into the Gmail
>   search box. Select the conversation
>   you want to unmute (demute?), and from
>   the drop-down menu choose **Move to inbox**.
>   That will restore new message
>   notifications on that thread from
>   there on out.

[Source](http://lifehacker.com/333290/how-do-i-unmute-a-gmail-conversation)